# Migrating CouchDB 1.x to 2.x using "couchup" utility

Tags: couchdb-2.0

I currently am trying to convert my couchdb 1.6.1 files to couchdb 2.1.1

I am trying to use the "couchup" utility recommended by Apache in there documentation ( http://docs.couchdb.org/en/latest/install/upgrading.html )

I copied my files from the old directory   (E:\CouchDB\var\lib\couchdb)  to
the new one E:\CoucchBD\data).

When I run  "py couchup list" it successfully lists my unconverted couch db files:

[screenshot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t7rjJ.png)

When I run  "py couchup replicate -a -l  -p "  it fails

Comment: 2.  after also had add the couchdb  login and password

Comment: hi, how did you install couchup?

Answer (score 1):

There were 2  problems I had fix to get this work

1. My cluster couchDB was not setup correctly.

   a.  I forgot to change the -name in vm.args  (and they were both nodes named couchDB@localhost .   I had rename these to couchDB@

   b. required my to uninstall/ reinstall my nodes, proproperly update my 
       vm.args files and reconfigure the cluster
2. On both nodes, I had comment out my [admins] login and password line my local.ini file and restart the couchDB service.  This was because my long password in combination with 64bit encoding was couching the part of couchup utility.

After this I was successfully able to replicate most of my database.   I had to trim down  When done I re-enable my password